# Fast operations on arrays for game graphics

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, graphics, pygame

I've been programming for a while, but I have little experience with graphics, GUIs, event collection, etc. Recently I'm trying to write a simple game with game-of-lifey mechanics. That's why I want to control pixel by pixel.

I'm using pygame and surfarray.blit_array(), which works pretty good, except framerates are quite bad, about 5 fps. I found out, that there is no problem with pixel drawing - when I use numpy arrays and utilize fill(), fps is very, very fast. But when I try a simple program, that sets random values to array elements it gets very slow, around said 5 fps.

I tried operating on list of lists instead of numpy arrays, and then convert it to a numpy array, but it wasn't much faster.

What am I doing wrong? I've read that using SDL in C++ allows for better framerates, but here the problem seems to be with array manipulation, not graphics handling.

EDIT:
Sorry, I guess I overcomplicated everything. The core of my problem is that such program:

```
import time
import numpy
import random

a = numpy.zeros((600,600))

b = time.clock()

for i in range(600):
    for j in range(600):
        if random.random()>0.5:
            a[i][j] = 1
        else:
            a[i][j] = 0

print(time.clock()-b)
```

takes 0.26 seconds, so simply rendering noise is impossible. I guess there must be a faster way. I'm using IDLE Python 3.4

Comment: A correctly written "game" has the logical backend (the algorithm and data structure) and the graphical frontend (taking the data from the backend and just presenting it). So first identify where is your bottleneck - on the backend or the frontend, and then solve it.

Comment: @Jan Do you understand that the amount of guesswork one should do to try and answer your question is possibly too much? In other words, would you please show us the code, intending a short, significative excerpt of it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an array, you might as well use an array-based function. Any time you step through every single point an an array there is probably a better solution. In this case, you could just use numpy.random.randint()

```
import numpy as np
b = time.clock()    
a = np.random.randint(2,size=(600,600))
print time.clock() - b
```

will return you a 600 x 600 array of 0's and 1's. In my case, the output was `0.006798`.

(Done in python 2.7, but numpy functionality should be the same).